# Nested dynamic function objects in rust

Tags: function, dynamic, rust, nested, box

I'm trying to build an object for nested function calls.
The idea is to write something based on simple common expressions such as f64 + f64.
The Expr object then builds something similar to a parsed mathematical expression by
implementing it's own arithmetic operations and acting on its children.
Theoretically, one would then call the upper Expr object and it will in turn call its children and so own until an Expr with no children is found and the result can be propagated backwards.

However, I am unable to satisfy the compiler regarding moved objects (The code below doesn't compile)...
I would appreciate any help!

```
use std::ops::Add;

pub struct Expr {
    children: (Box<Option<Expr>>, Box<Option<Expr>>), //children expressions
    func: Box<dyn Fn(f64, f64) -> f64>, //expr's function
}

impl Add<Expr> for Expr {
    type Output = Expr;

    fn add(self, rhs: Expr) -> Self::Output {
        let children = (Box::new(Some(self)), Box::new(Some(rhs)));
        let mut res = Expr {
            children,
            func: Box::new(|l, r| -> f64 { 1. }), //dummy function to be replaced
        };
        res.func = Box::new(
            |l, r| -> f64 {
                (&res.children.0.unwrap().func)(l, r) + (&res.children.1.unwrap().func)(l, r)
            }
        );
        res
    }
}
```

Comment: You make the struct `res` self-referential and then try to move it, which [doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct).

Comment: You should either have `func` take ownership of the two `Expr`s and remove `children` entirely, or `func` should be simple like `|l, r| l + r` where the children are calculated separately and then passed to `func`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `res.func` is stored in a `Box` on the heap, that itself is not connected to `res.children`, even though both of the boxes are stored in the same Expr. If the function would know about this `Expr`, all would be fine because it could use the `Expr` to access `children`. But it does not know about it, it is just stored in one and all it knows about are things that either were captured when the closure was created or whatever arguments you give to it. (When you look in your own mail*box*, you don't get to look in your neighbour's mail*box* too, unless they have given you the key.)

What would make more sense is to implement a function on `Expr` that gets the values and then calls the function with them, allowing you to write a more simple closure as @kmdreko commented. The function could look something like this:

```
impl Expr {
    pub fn do_the_thing(self) -> Option<f64> {
        let left = (*self.children.0)?.do_the_thing()?;
        let right = (*self.children.1)?.do_the_thing()?;
        Some((self.func)(left, right))
    }
}
```

This would then allow you to simplify the implementation of `Add`:

```
impl Add<Expr> for Expr {
    type Output = Expr;

    fn add(self, rhs: Expr) -> Self::Output {
        let children = (Box::new(Some(self)), Box::new(Some(rhs)));
        Expr {
            children,
            func: Box::new(|l, r| l + r),
        }
    }
}
```